# Having two interfaces and configured through netplan, VM not connecting to internet

Tags: networking, netplan

My yaml file looks like this

```yaml
network:
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
     dhcp4: yes
     addresses: [192.168.1.209/24]
     gateway4: 192.168.1.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
     dhcp4-overrides:
       route-metric: 100
     routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 192.168.1.1
         metric: 3
    eth1:
      dhcp4: yes
      addresses: [169.254.0.39/24]
      dhcp4-overrides:
        route-metric: 200
      gateway: 169.254.0.38
  version: 2
```

And my `ip route get` is

```
ip route get 1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 via 169.254.0.38 dev eth1 src 169.254.0.39 uid 1000
    cache
```

and my `ip route` is as follows

```
default via 169.254.0.38 dev eth1 proto static
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto static
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 3
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.11 metric 100
169.254.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.0.39
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.209
192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.11 metric 100
```

When I access my `192` gateway it works fine but internet access goes through `169` which is a private network. I also tried use route-metric but failing at it.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default route metric, when none is otherwise specified, is 0; which means that in your config, when you specify `gateway: 169.254.0.38` on `eth1`, you are creating a route with the lowest metric - and therefore the highest priority.

Since you mention that this is a private network and you don't want your Internet traffic to go via this interface, you should really not be specifying a gateway here at all, because a gateway is shorthand for a default route.

According to your routing table, you are also not getting this default route via DHCP, only via your `gateway` declaration.

The following configuration is likely sufficient:

```
network:
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
     dhcp4: yes
     addresses: [192.168.1.209/24]
     nameservers:
       addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
    eth1:
      addresses: [169.254.0.39/24]
  version: 2
```

Differences:

- don't specify a gateway or routes anywhere; your `ip route` output shows that you are getting the route you want via dhcp already
- don't run dhcp on eth1, there's no indication that it's doing anything for you (but showing the output of `ip a` would confirm)
- don't bother with dhcp overrides; now that you're only getting routes on one interface, you don't need to change the metrics

This does retain your manually specified address of 192.168.1.209/24 on eth0, which is a different address than the one you are being given by dhcp (192.168.1.11).  I am assuming it is intentional on your part to have two IPs assigned to this interface.

Comment: Oh awesome, this totally worked and excellent explanation!